# How to prettify/format an XML buffer?

Tags: formatting, nxml, xml

I have a file with xml all on one line. Does the functionality already exist to reformat this buffer to be somewhat user-readable?

Comment: FWIW this question was asked on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492/pretty-printing-xml-files-on-emacs

Comment: I like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/570049/8583496

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Does the functionality already exist to reformat this buffer to be somewhat user-readable?

Of course, and you have plenty of options. I'd probably feed it to an external program using:

```
C-x h C-u M-| xmllint --format - RET
```

This program comes with [`libxml2`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/). You could also use [`tidy`](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/). Here's a list of commandline xml formatting tools: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090869/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-the-command-line

You could also do a search and replace and then indent:

`M-% > < RET > C-q C-j < RET ! C-M-\`

Neat trick: you can copy and paste the above string into `M-:` (`eval-expression`) like this:

```
(execute-kbd-macro (kbd "M-% > < RET > C-q C-j < RET ! C-M-\\"))
```

Comment: A nice answer, but be wary that the command as written now will replace the buffer content with the output from the shell command.  This is because of the `C-u` prefix.

Answer (score 33):

The built-in `sgml-mode` has a command to do this: `sgml-pretty-print`. If you're in `nxml-mode` it looks like you need switch to `sgml-mode` first. You could write a command to temporarily switch to sgml-mode, run pretty-print, then switch back to nxml-mode.

For example, here is a command that will pretty-print the region, optionally with auto-fill enabled:

```
(defun xml-pretty-print (beg end &optional arg)
  "Reformat the region between BEG and END.
    With optional ARG, also auto-fill."
  (interactive "*r\nP")
  (let ((fill (or (bound-and-true-p auto-fill-function) -1)))
    (sgml-mode)
    (when arg (auto-fill-mode))
    (sgml-pretty-print beg end)
    (nxml-mode)
    (auto-fill-mode fill)))
```

Comment: In Emacs 26.1, `sgml-pretty-print` works directly from the nxml mode.

Answer (score 16):

Mark your xml and do:

```
M-x sgml-pretty-print
```

Or just run the command without a marked region to prettify the whole buffer.

Answer (score 7):

write this into your `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(require 'sgml-mode)

(defun ninrod/reformat-xml ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (sgml-pretty-print (point-min) (point-max))
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))))
```

reload emacs, then just call `M-x reformat-xml` on the badly formatted xml buffer.

source: https://davidcapello.com/blog/emacs/reformat-xml-on-emacs/

Comment: He's not asking for something to reformat it. He's asking for something to make it human readable.

Answer (score 5):

In `nxml-mode`, <kbd>C-x H</kbd> will mark the whole buffer and <kbd>TAB</kbd> will indent the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint of the answer above, and assuming you have `tidy` installed a variation could be:

```
`C-x h M-| tidy -quiet -xml -utf8 -indent -`
```

This will open a new buffer `*Shell Command Output*` instead of directly replacing the contents of the buffer. After checking the result, replace the old contents with the new with:

```
C-x h M-insert-buffer
```

choose the suggested default which will probably be `*Shell Command Output*`. You can save the command for later with a keyboard macro:

```
C-x ( C-x h M-| tidy -quiet -xml -utf8 -indent - C-x)
C-x C-k n pretty-xml
```

With this you can execute `M-x pretty-xml` to reformat the buffer.